# "Command not found" when sourcing file with path variables

Tags: bash, variables

If I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_PATH="/Users/hudson/workspace/Foo"
XCODE_PROJECT_FOLDER="${PROJECT_PATH}/CODE/APP/FOO_IOS"

echo ${PROJECT_PATH}
echo ${XCODE_PROJECT_FOLDER}
```

It displays:

> /Users/hudson/workspace/Foo
>
> /Users/hudson/workspace/Foo/CODE/APP/FOO_IOS

If I put the variables in another file, include it in the main script file, and run it:

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

. "/Users/hudson/workspace/Foo/ota.sh"

echo ${PROJECT_PATH}
echo ${XCODE_PROJECT_FOLDER}
```

**/Users/hudson/workspace/Foo/ota.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_PATH="/Users/hudson/workspace/Foo"
XCODE_PROJECT_FOLDER="${PROJECT_PATH}/CODE/APP/FOO_IOS"
```

I have this output:

> : command not found /Users/hudson/workspace/Foo/ota.sh: line 2:
>
> /Users/hudson/workspace/Foo
>
> /CODE/APP/FOO_IOSkspace/Foo

Any idea of where the problem could come from?

- If I put ota.sh in the same folder as test.sh, this works well
- If I don't let a blank line between #!/bin/bash and the inclusion, I don't get the : command not foundpace/Foo/ota.sh: line 2 message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably wrong/mixed unix/windows line endings, try to fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: I write the scripts files as follow: I write them on Windows using Notepad++, and copy/paste the content of the files through TightVNC to a mac, in XCode. How could I harmonize the line endings?

Comment: in resent version of ubuntu, dos2unix is replaced with `fromdos` and `todos`

Comment: @Mike: first of all check with a hex editor that this is really the case. to fix it use `vi`, or any unix tool eg: `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g'`

Comment: @yi_H: I've edited my post with a PS, which tends to make me think that this is not an ending line problem

Comment: @yi_H: I've runned "perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g' test.sh" and "perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g' include.sh" and I still get the error

Comment: there must be some crazy character there, line 2 should be empty.

Comment: @Mike, did you try `dos2unix` or `fromdos`? Also, `od -c filename` is a handy tool to view the characters in the file.

Comment: That was indeed a line ending bug. The od -c filename command allowed me to see that. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in `vim`, to see if there are any special characters there, like backspace.

Comment: I just did, and couldn't see any weird character

Answer (score 0):

As with the previous answer, probably wrong/mixed unix/windows line endings. If you are using notepad++,as Mike mentioned, in notepadd++, you can change the EOL character(s) by choosing the Edit menu, then **EOL Conversion**. After reading Mike's comment, that is what fixed this same exact problem that the op mentioned, that I was having too.